# Bootstrap tabs are not working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap tabs on page load my active tab is working but if i click on second tab Compliance rating i am not getting tab contents its re-directing to home page. Any idea where i am doing wrong ?

tabs.html

```
<div role="tabpanel">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#lob"
       aria-controls="lob" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Line of
        Business Ratings</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#cr"
        aria-controls="cr" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Compliance
       Rating</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="lob">
       ON PAGE LOAD THIS TAB IS WORKING 
      </div>
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="cr"> 
        <h1>Compliance code......</h1> 
      </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, is that the result you are expecting?

https://jsfiddle.net/pv68f9xh/

This is what happens when I load ur code with the library exactly. It seems to be working. Can you show me your javascript that you have so far? Or did you forgot to load both javascript and css library of bootstrap?

Comment: i have bootstrap and css both libraries in the project. Do you know which bootstrap library specifically you are pointing for above tabs ?

Comment: In my fiddle you mean? I'm using this CDN as external ressources: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/  it's the latest version of bootstrap I believe

Comment: You also need jQuery loaded before you load bootstrap. Do you have it loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these two scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
```