# My Bootstrap tabs are not clickable. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4

I'm writing a Bootstrap website. I made some progress but occasionally face some issues I can't resolve on my own. For example, I added a set of tabs which are supposed to be interactive, but they aren't. What irks me is that my code is apparently identical to [what](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_navs.php) *w3schools* show. Here's my code

```html
<!-- yes, it's tabs inside another tab -->
<div id="admin-tab" class="col-sm-11 m-1">
<!-- I commented out this div wrap just to see whether it helps, it doesn't -->
<!--            <div class="row">-->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs m-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#users-table">All Users</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#add-new-user">Add New User</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
<!--            </div>-->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="users-table" class="tab-pane container active table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                        <!-- here goes the table -->
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="add-new-user" class="tab-pane container">
                    <!-- here goes the add-new-user content -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's *w3*'s code

```html
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu1">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu2">...</div>
</div>
```

Considering the fact that the pieces are the same, it may have something to do with my `<script>` imports, but Claude (a chat bot) says they are fine

```html
<!-- I decided to show you my head element too, just in case -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Admin Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- some body code -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- the imports are just at the end of the body -->
</body>
```

I tried double-checking my code to see how it corresponds to the *w3schools* instructions. I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045704/navigation-buttons-are-not-clickable-on-my-bootstrap-template) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201273/bootstrap-tabs-are-not-working) posts, but they appear outdated and (no longer) relevant

**Why are my tabs not clickable and how to I fix it?**

Comment: I hope it's legit what I just did. I believe it may help folks who struggle with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you experienced has to do with the fact that you're following a Bootstrap 5 tutorial while having a Bootstrap 4 import

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In particular, your Bootstrap 4 script doesn't get what on earth `data-bs-toggle` is

```html
<li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#add-new-user">Add New User</a>
                    </li>
```

If you change it to `data-toggle="tab"`, it'll work like a charm

[image]

Now, if you're interested in why they changed `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle` in Bootstrap 5, you may want to read [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/b38110aa7de32ec71cec4f03342ff0c7f29f2991) commit commentary

> Data attributes for all JavaScript plugins are now namespaced to help distinguish Bootstrap functionality from third parties and your own code. For example, we use `data-bs-toggle` instead of `data-toggle`.